# What is the difference between "tun","machen", and "schaffen"?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

What is the difference between "*tun*", "*machen*", and "*schaffen*"?

I have seen those words as "*do*", for example, in

> - Ich *tue* es. → I *do* it.
> - Ich *mache* es selber. → I *do* it myself.
> - Ich kann es *schaffen*. → I can *do* it.

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Wir schaffen das"** means: We will make it. I know that I will make it. We will achieve it.

**"Wir tun es"** is identical with   **"Wir machen es"**: We carry something out!

But there's a slight difference between **tun** (-> Tat) and **machen**:

*(but only in certain cases!)*

machen = to produce something

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/machen

tun = to execute something

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tun

Comment: Wir machen Feierabend. Was tust Du? Schlafen.

Comment: OK: Ich führe den Schlaf aus, klar? Macht nichts. Produziert nichts ;) Ich sags ja, es ist nur eine leichte Nuance.

Comment: Note that *schaffen* exists both as a strong and as a weak verb. As a strong verb (Ich schaffe/schuf/habe geschaffen) it means "to create". In "Ich schaffe es", meaning "I will do it/make it" it is a weak verb (Ich schaffe es/schaffte es/habe es geschafft). Weak "schaffen" is also used as a synonym of "arbeiten" in some regions.

Answer (score 2):

*schaffen* in that sense is rather idiomatic and doesn't compare well to *tun* and *machen*. Personally, I lexicalize it as *reach*, "bis ins Ziel geschaft", hence "ich schaffe es". That's probably closer to "etwas wohin schaffen" (to bring something somewhere). This sense might be influenced by *schieben* (to push, move); cp. *to shove*. The other, I might say regular, interpretation is found in *erschaffen* (create); cp. *herstellen* vs *hinstellen*.

I think *tun* is in many cases proscribed (forbidden), ie. it's never used as auxiliary and doesn't appear in composita (at least not frequently). In English, occasions of a bare *do* actually stem from an understanding of it replacing a complex verbal phrase. "Do I go to the shop? I do!" (or even "Yes, I am"; at least, I saw that once explained as standing in for a present continuous construction in a context where that tense hadn't even been used before). "tun" has gotten a connotation of pretension, "er tut nur so" (he's faking it). Plattdeutsch "tut das Not?" (*ist das nötig* - is that needed/necessary) is obviously closer to the English channel. The civil law code knows *Tun* only as noun or in "kundtun" (synonym "kundgeben", "bekannt geben"); Searching the text, I came to wonder whether *-tung* is a legitimate suffix related to *thing* ...

Whereas *machen* is used almost like an auxiliary verb, e.g. "Musik, Krach machen" (make music, noise), "Feierabend machen" (to end the workday), "bekannt machen" (to make known) and somewhat weird, IMHO, in "Aufwendungen ... gemacht" in the civil law code. In some cases it corresponds to *haben* "Freunde machen, Freunde haben" (to make friends, to have friends) and "Feierabend haben"; Not so for "Krach haben" (to have a disagreement). *machen* may be used in dialect as *to go*, "wir machen nach Leipzig" (we make for Leipzig), or perhaps "mach dich vom Acker" (get lost), "los machen" (to leave, make off). It's generally used colloquially for *move, set, place*, "mach das da hin", where others might prefer "tue/setze/stelle/lege das dorthin"; There's also "etwas ab machen" (to remove something [e.g. dirt from clothes]), "das geht nicht ab" (it doesn't come off) and more abstract verbal phrases like "eine Abmachung treffen", thus "etwas abmachen" (to make an appointent, agreement).

Along those lines, *become* vs *bekommen* and *get* should also be compared.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to like your answer, but I don't have enough reputation, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say

- I do it myself -> ich tue es selber
- I can do it -> ich kann es tun

But it sounds not that good, cause in german "tun" isn't used as much as "do" is in english.

Also possible is
"machen" is "make"
and "schaffen" is "accomplish"